# The view rendering only once

Tags: angularjs

My view is rendering correctly for the first time, but when I reload the state using:

```
$state.reload();
```

it loads but one directive doesn't. The data is requested via DataService every time controller reload and every time I receive it.

```
DataService.getWidgetsList().then(function (data) {
    $scope.widgets = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log($scope.widgets);
   // I receive correct JSON data every time here
});
```

My View code:

```
<div mix-it-up class="sandbox tiles" ng-if="widgets" id="sandbox">
    <div class="mix tile {{getColour(widget.widgetTypeId)}} cat{{widget.widgetCategoryId}}" data-myorder="{{widget.title}}" ng-click="setWidget(widget.id)"
         ng-repeat="widget in widgets" modal-view-url="WidgetPreviewModal" modal-controller="widgetPreviewController" modal-size="lg">
        <div class=" tile-body">
            <i class="{{getIcon(widget.widgetTypeId)}}"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="tile-object">
            <div class="name">
                {{widget.title}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gap"></div>
    <div class="gap"></div>
</div>
```

My directive:

```
var mixItUp = function ($compile, $timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            angular.element(element).mixItUp({
        });
    }}};

mixItUp.$inject = ['$compile', '$timeout'];
```

is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't you follow `.directive` notation?

Comment: I do mate, the .directive notation is on different page. Is it relevant here?

Comment: Probably you should create a fiddle of this.